# Securing Google Cloud Functions run in background

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud Functions as a background functions to listen to an incoming CSV file on GS bucket and subsequently trigger a Cloud SQL Import (MySQL).

I am able to successfully test this flow and see the CSV file data loaded into Cloud SQL.

However, I would like to validate this approach from a security perspective and also explore if there are any other better options.

I understanding is that since there is no http endpoint exposed for the Cloud Functions (backgrounder function), there should not be a security loophole.

Wanted to validate this from others and flag if there is anything specific I need to take care.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions have several possible triggers: [[Event triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers)]

- HTTP—invoke functions directly via HTTP requests
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Pub/Sub
- Firebase (DB, Storage, Analytics, Auth)

You can configure Cloud Functions access control depending on your needs. [[Cloud Functions doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam)]

If you are using GCS (Google Cloud Storage) as trigger you need to configure GCS access control properly. [[GCS doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/)]

If you control the entry-point (GCS in this case) everything should go well.